# Why maintain two-way pointers in data design?

Tags: database, mongodb, many-to-many, one-to-many, data-modeling

Assume I have the following schema:

**BOOKS COLLECTION:**

```
{
    author: { ...authorObject }
}
```

**AUTHORS COLLECTION:**

```
{
    books: [{ ...bookObject}]
}
```

If I'm already storing the author's information on each book document, why should I store an array of books on each author document? Wouldn't it suffice to query from the books collection whenever I want to see all the books a particular author has written?

I found a similar schema here: https://www.howtographql.com/graphql-js/6-authentication/

Every link has a "postedBy" field, and each user has a "links" field. Why store the same information in both places? Isn't it inefficient? For instance, if one removes a link (or a book in the example above), you'd have to update the corresponding user's (or author's) document.

Just trying to understand why we need to store the **same** information in **both** directions. Feels a bit redundant.

Comment: See [Data Modeling Introduction](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/data-modeling-introduction/) for some ideas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it depends on your use cases. Says you only maintain 1-way pointer that keeps books array in author document, if you have a use case that requires searching for author by a certain book, you will need to do a full collection scan of author collection to find all matches. So without much knowledge of your actual scenario, it could be hard for us to comment on the necessity of 2 way pointer in your database.

[This document](https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/6-rules-of-thumb-for-mongodb-schema-design-part-1) is a good piece for your reading.